# react-router error by browserify-shim react

Tags: javascript, react-router

react-router error by browserify-shim react

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined

buy it's fine to package the react toggle~

help~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every module rely on react like react-router should add the behind config to its own package.

```js
"browserify-shim": {
  "react": "global:React"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
```